# Jquery toggle-trigger - hide and show a text

Tags: jquery

i'm new in Jquery and i need to show and hide a lot of products on a site. actually im using this script:

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".toggle-trigger").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.toggle-wrap').first().toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<p><a class="toggle-trigger">TITLE</a><p>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
    <div class="style-single">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>

<p><a class="toggle-trigger"> TITLE </a><p>
<div class="toggle-wrap">
    <div class="style-single">
        TEXT
    </div>
</div>
```

But, when i click on the page, all the elements shows up and hide when click. I need the inverse of this, when the page loads, all elements are hide and when click the item shows up... how do i do?

Comment: _"all the elements shows up and hide when click"_ I see no click handler so I don't know why clicking would do anything on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is needlessly complex. Try this:

```
$(this).parent().next('.toggle-wrap').toggle('slow');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fpeozu4j/)**

Note: I corrected your closing paragraph tags. That's the primary issue and your original code **[works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/fpeozu4j/2/)** when that's done.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you wanted to toggle on click (and also like isherwood mentioned, fix your open `<p>` tags)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle-trigger").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().next('.toggle-wrap').stop().toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

The idea is, you want to toggle the show/hide animation on click. I also added `stop` to kill any active transitions

You also want to hide your drop down text on initial load by applying some CSS

```
<style>
    .toggle-wrap{
        display:none    
    }
</style>
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/046wvcja/

Comment: im really newbie. where i apply the CSS? i'm using wordpress and this is the page http://imperialquimica.com.br/?page_id=18 . i've made the changes on script and closed the <p>, but still don't working...

Comment: usually you will have a style sheet file specified where you define your styles like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">` or you can specify in html within style tags for one offs. see above for css with style tags to be placed within the html